# Java Field Watchpoints in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, breakpoints, watchpoint

Whole day i am trying to debug my app with Java Field Watchpoints, set on any type of field : string , int ... but it just wont stop. 
I am using tablet with 4.4.2 android and 2.0 Android Studio.
Breakpoints work normally.

Comment: are you starting the app with the debugger attached ?

Comment: of course. i am not total begginer

Comment: does the breakpoint has an x inside red circle ?

Comment: nop. it is labeld "-"

Answer (score -1):

You can break on value changes of some variables in Android Studio.

Android Studio calls them 'Java Field Watchpoints'.

From the breakpoints windows, (Run -> "View breakpoints...") or Ctrl+Shift+F8, you can add "Java Field Watchpoints" from the plus in the top left corner, and then select your class and variable

Comment: tnx mate i appreciate it very much that you wana help , but i already  know   all that . Point is it does not work.